# Function that reads and displays slider value in different colors

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to create a function that reads a value obtained from a slider and then displays it, in different colors according to its value.

This is the code I have so far:

```js
function slider() {
  document.getElementById("formControlRange").oninput = function() {
    percentagem()
  };
}

function percentagem() {
  var val = document.getElementById("formControlRange").value document.getElementById('formOutput').innerHTML = val
  if ($("#formControlRange").val() >=
    50) {
    $("#formOutput").addClass("alert-sucess");
  } else {
    $("#formOutput").addClass("alert-danger");
  }
}
console.log(val)
}
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="formControlRange">Com que percentagem recomendaria o Bootstrap a terceiros?</label>
    <input type="range" class="form-control-range" id="formControlRange" onchange="slider()" min="0" max="100">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <h1><output id="formOutput" class=""></output></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add "alert" class to your element if you want "alert-success" and "alert-danger" to work. And you must reset the classes every time the value change. Plus be carefull on semicolons and curly braces.

```js
function slider() {
  document.getElementById("formControlRange").oninput = function() {
    percentagem()
  };
}

function percentagem() {
  var val = document.getElementById("formControlRange").value;
  document.getElementById('formOutput').innerHTML = val;
  $("#formOutput").removeClass("alert-sucess alert-danger");
  if ($("#formControlRange").val() >= 50) {
    $("#formOutput").addClass("alert-success");
  } else {
    $("#formOutput").addClass("alert-danger");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="formControlRange">Com que percentagem recomendaria o Bootstrap a terceiros?</label>
    <input type="range" class="form-control-range" id="formControlRange" onchange="slider()" min="0" max="100">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <h1><output id="formOutput" class="alert"></output></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```